# Install NumPy for Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am using python 3.5 and I am trying to install NumPy but when I try to install from command prompt using command: pip install numpy

I get a whole lot of errors. The main error though seems to be at the end: error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

I have also tried downloading the numpy binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy and installing using command: pip install numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

But I get an error that says: numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Then I found a numpy-1.10.2-win32-superpack-python3.4.exe file here https://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.10.2/ but when I try to run that I get an error that I require Python version 3.4.

I looked and cannot find an installer for python 3.5.exe, do I need to uninstall python 3.5 and install 3.4 instead? Or is there anyway to install numpy for Python 3.5?

I am using Windows 10/64 bit.

Comment: Sometimes when using Windows it is better to fall back on an earlier python version since many packages and modules have not yet been finished for windows in the latest versions, it is a common error, it also happens with some ruby packages, since most programming is done on Linux, and therefore it takes a bit of time before they finally get released for Windows. Linux takes priority almost 100% of the time. I'd sugest (unless it is mandatory to use Windows) to use a virtual box and do your coding on Linux on your Windows computer.

Comment: For example, in Debian testing, currently, package python3-numpy has version 1:1.10.4-2 and depends on both python3.4 & python3.5. In fact I suspect there's some mistake in those dependencies...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way to obtain numpy, scipy, pandas, ... is to install anaconda. 
Anaconda will automatically download and install the latest modules.
https://www.continuum.io/downloads

I hope this will help you along.

Comment: thanks, I tried installing anaconda and its solved all my problems.